# websockets - ws with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to push messages from server to client using ws module in node.js application.

Please find below the code in app.js.

```
var server = app.listen(port);
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server});
wss.on('connection', function (ws) {

    console.log('connected');
});

ws.on('message', function (data, flags) {

});
```

});

code in the client side js file.

```
    window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
    var host = window.document.location.host.replace(/:.*/, '');
    var port = window.document.location.port;
    var socketConnection = new WebSocket('ws://'+ host+':'+ port);        
    socketConnection.onerror = function (error) {
        // TODO : report error here..
    };         
    socketConnection.onmessage = function (message) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(message.data)          

    };
```

The problem is when i'm running the node application locally.i.e http://localhost:port and when I try to handshake with ws connection through "ws://localhost:port\". The handshake happens and i am able to send and receive messages.

But when i access the same application using the ip of my machine i.e as http://10.xx.yy.zz:port. Im able to open the application and do evrything but the handshake with websockets time out. The same happens when the app is running in another machine and i try to connect to it from my machines browser.The handshake doesnot happen and it times out.

I have tried the same with demos provided out of box by ws module. The same happens. Am I missing something when creating the websocket server?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a server config problem? Firewalls, ports, iptables, everything must be taken in consideration.

Comment: Firewall is disabled and port is open and listening. tested it with netstat cmd. If the issue was with port/firewall then shouldn't http requests also fail? thanks!!